# UITableView reloadData Crashes During Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, crash, scroll, reloaddata

I have a UITableView with a refresh button in toolbar.
If the TableView is stopped and I press refresh button calling `reloadData` everything work fine.
But if I'm scrolling the tableview and press refresh button before tableview stops, the app crashes with this message:

`-[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 31 beyond bounds for empty array'`

I think that with the scroll, app is trying build cell reading a array that `reloadData` cleared.

I'm trying to stop the scroll before `reloadData`, but it does not work.
Any idea?

Comment: I resolved using another array in datasource and make a copy berfore reloaddata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly not a solution to this problem, as you have not posted any code  !

But, I would like to know why you would want to refresh the data while scrolling ? In the usability perspective, I do not think the users would do that either. I am guessing you are just testing the view with certain cases so that your app does not crash !

I would suggest that you make the `UIButton` inactive when it's scrolling while the tableView is being scrolled.

```
myButton.enabled = NO;

// after scrolling you can set it to YES.
```

I really do not believe that users would want to refresh the table while the `tableView` is scrolling, and if they press it accidentally, I think that little piece of code would fix the issue.

Comment: Is this an OK solution to this problem? I was attempting to move reloadData to another thread, but I read some articles saying not to do so. This is an easy solution, but it doesn't seem ok to me, considering the user experience. :-